# sorting an array according, continuously, like simulating a shortest job first

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Okay, straight to the point, I have this array:

```
var arr = [
        {
            "job": "j1",
            "at": 0,
            "bt": 8
        },
        {
            "job": "j2",
            "at": 2,
            "bt": 3
        },
        {
            "job": "j3",
            "at": 3,
            "bt": 1
        },
        {
            "job": "j1",
            "at": 6,
            "bt": 3
        }
    ]
```

where `at` is the arrival time, and `bt` is the burst time. Okay I have this sort function:

```
Array.prototype.sort = function(by) {
  this.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a[by] < b[by])
      return -1;
    if(a[by] > b[by])
      return 1;
    return 0;
  });
};
```

That sorts an Array of object according to the given parameter. Now I wanted iterate all of the elements, and then iterate through each element's burst time, and stop when any of the other elements contains an arrival time that is equal to the current time. When a match is found, compare their burst time, if the burst time of the another element is lesser, subtract the elapsed time of the current element to its burst time, and move on to the next element.

So far I have that logic, and still can't find a way to implement it:

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(j = arr[i].at; j < arr[i].bt; j++){
    // some other things 
    }
}
```

Comment: So effectively you're ordering by `at` ascending, then by `bt` ascending?

Answer (score 1):

Given the calculation on `bt`, you are effectively ordering by `bt` as a secondary sort. Try this:

```
Array.prototype.sort = function(by) {
    this.sort(function(a,b){
        if (a[by] < b[by])
            return -1;

        if (a[by] > b[by])
            return 1;

        if (a[by] == b[by]) {
            if (a['bt'] < b['bt']) 
                return -1;

            if (a['bt'] > b['bt'])
                 return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    });
};
```

Comment: i think i have failed clear out what I wanted, damn, its too hard to explain ughhh

Comment: if you are familiar with this : http://guptapreeti.blogspot.com/2012/03/example-of-preemptive-sjf.html

this is kinda what I want to simulate